# update field when others fields are motifed

Tags: java

I have a class `Installment` and a method `executeTransaction`. The field `totalBalance` represents the difference between total due and total paid. Inside method `executeTransaction` the installment object is modified using setters. And after every setter the updateTotalBalance is called.

```java
    public class Installment {
        private BigDecimal principalDue;
        private BigDecimal principalPaid;
        private BigDecimal interestDue;
        private BigDecimal interestPaid;
        private BigDecimal feeDue;
        private BigDecimal feePaid;
        private BigDecimal penaltyDue;
        private BigDecimal penaltyPaid;
        private BigDecimal totalBalance;

        public void updateTotalBalance() {
             this.totalBalance = this.principalDue.subtract(this.penaltyPaid)
                .add(this.interestDue).subtract(this.interestPaid)
                .add(this.feeDue).subtract(this.feePaid)
                .add(this.penaltyDue).subtract(this.penaltyPaid);
        }

        //seters
        //getters
    }
```

Transaction method:

```java
    public void executeTransaction(Installment installment){
        //code
        installment.setPrincipalPaid(bigDecimalValue);
        installment.updateTotalBalance();
        //code
        installment.setPenaltyDue(bigDecimalValue);
        installment.updateTotalBalance();
    }
```

I was thinking about putting the `updateTotalBalance` inside the setters, but for me both of these approaches seem contradictory with the best design principles.
Q: I want to know if there are better solutions to update a field in a class when others fields are modified.

Comment: the most popular solution calls 'update' ones - after all sets are done. If this code's client are going to set something else on top (let assume you domain logic supposes such a behaviour) then 'update' call becomes a burden of this client.  All ideas (the original as well) need synch-work to yet be done (if there is such a req).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) by isoliting (delegating) the calculation in another object and keep the `Installment` as a simple POJO.

```java
public class Calculator {

    public BigDecimal balance(Installment installment) {
        return installment.getPrincipalDue().subtract(installment.getPenaltyPaid())
                .add(installment.getInterestDue()).subtract(installment.getInterestPaid())
                .add(installment.getFeeDue()).subtract(installment.getFeePaid())
                .add(installment.getPenaltyDue()).subtract(installment.getPenaltyPaid());
    }
}
```

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Value
public class Installment {
    private BigDecimal principalDue;
    private BigDecimal principalPaid;
    private BigDecimal interestDue;
    private BigDecimal interestPaid;
    private BigDecimal feeDue;
    private BigDecimal feePaid;
    private BigDecimal penaltyDue;
    private BigDecimal penaltyPaid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`totalBalance` should not be a normal field because it makes `Installment` *[illogical data structure](https://youtu.be/-lVVfxsRjcY?t=1753)*.

> **Illogical data structure** is one which can, by its definition, take on nonsensical values.

In your case, `Installment` is *illogical* because `totalBalance` field may contain an incorrect value, so you have to replace this field with method `getTotalBalance`.

If you don't want `totalBalance` being recalculated each time, you can apply [lazy loading idiom](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/lazy-loading/). Here is how you can do it:

```
public class Installment {
    private BigDecimal principalDue;
    private BigDecimal principalPaid;
    private BigDecimal interestDue;
    private BigDecimal interestPaid;
    private BigDecimal feeDue;
    private BigDecimal feePaid;
    private BigDecimal penaltyDue;
    private BigDecimal penaltyPaid;
    private final ResettableLazyHolder<BigDecimal> totalBalance =
            new ResettableLazyHolder<>(this::calculateTotalBalance);

    private BigDecimal calculateTotalBalance() {
        return principalDue.subtract(penaltyPaid)
                .add(interestDue).subtract(interestPaid)
                .add(feeDue).subtract(feePaid)
                .add(penaltyDue).subtract(penaltyPaid);
    }

    // Always assign fields with setters even in private context
    public void setPrincipalDue(BigDecimal principalDue) {
        // add this line to each setter
        totalBalance.reset();
        this.principalDue = principalDue;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalBalance() {
        return totalBalance.get();
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

Where `ResettableLazyHolder` is:

```
public class ResettableLazyHolder<T> {
    private boolean initialized = false;
    private T value;
    private final Supplier<? extends T> initializer;

    public ResettableLazyHolder(Supplier<? extends T> initializer) {
        this.initializer = initializer;
    }

    // add synchronized if you need thread-safety
    public T get() {
        // it's not enough to check that value == null because null can be a valid value
        if(!initialized) {
            value = initializer.get();
            initialized = true;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void reset() {
        initialized = false;
        value = null; // releases value for GC
    }
}
```